# Ubuntu 18.04.4 - Network Unclaimed After NIC Firmware Update

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, ethernet, nic

I recently updated the firmware on my HPE NC522SFP NIC so that it matches the corresponding NIC I have in my other machine (latest firmware). After doing this, Ubuntu no longer recognizes the card and states that it's "unclaimed" when running `lshw -C network` as you can see below (there's two listings, as it's a dual-port NIC). Unfortunately, installing drivers and/or downgrading the firmware is no simple task. All of the published Linux drivers are for OpenSUSE and RedHat (.RPM packages) and although I managed to install them with the help of Alien, it still won't work.

The firmware utilities are .scexe files, which don't seem to run at all for me. Downgrading the card would be an extensive process, and defeats what I'm trying to do anyways. Is there anything else I can try? My kernel version is 5.4.0-42-generic. Here's the output of lshw:

```
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter
       vendor: NetXen Incorporated
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 42
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe800000-fe9fffff memory:fc000000-fdffffff memory:febe0000-febeffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NX3031 Multifunction 1/10-Gigabit Server Adapter
       vendor: NetXen Incorporated
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       version: 42
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe600000-fe7fffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: d4:3d:7e:59:f7:a5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=10.0.0.60 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:f8fff000-f8ffffff memory:f8ff8000-f8ffbfff
```

**Edit #1**
Result of `sudo modprobe netxen_nic`: Blank. No errors or data

```
dmesg | grep -i netxen
[    1.687322] QLogic/NetXen Network Driver v4.0.82
[    1.687591] netxen_nic 0000:02:00.0: 2MB memory map
[    1.687883] netxen_nic 0000:02:00.0: Timeout reached  waiting for rom done
[    1.687889] netxen_nic 0000:02:00.0: Error getting board config info.
[    1.687977] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
[    1.688053] netxen_nic 0000:02:00.1: 2MB memory map
[    1.688334] netxen_nic 0000:02:00.1: Timeout reached  waiting for rom done
[    1.688336] netxen_nic 0000:02:00.1: Error getting board config info.
[    1.688402] netxen_nic: probe of 0000:02:00.1 failed with error -5
```

**Edit #2**
After swapping the cards out between my two systems it's somewhat resolved my issue. The card that was in my Windows machine works perfectly on my Ubuntu server, while the card that was in my server halfway works on my Windows machine. First boot? Works perfect. Restart? NIC isn't recognized by the system. Restart again? The boot animation doesn't even start, the system just reboots. Definitely something up with this card, will try to flash an older firmware to it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe netxen_nic` and also: `dmesg | grep -i netxen`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: OP updated. Modprobe came back blank, but dmesg definitely returned an error

Comment: "I recently updated the firmware" How, exactly? Did you actually update the ROM in the NIC hardware? I wonder if the process went wrong or the file was corrupted.

Comment: I updated using HP's firmware utility on a Windows based machine, as I did with the other card of the same model. I could try swapping the cards out later today and see what happens.

Comment: We look forward to the result.

Comment: Updated OP with my findings. Appears that this isn't an Ubuntu specific issue, so I've got some work to do. Thanks for your help!